# Can CDATA be used without using CharacterEscapeHandler for marshaling and unmarshalling in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

I don’t want to use CharacterEscapeHandler. Somehow want the newline character (\n) in java string (which is going to be an XML Attribute) needs to be there after marshall and unmarshall using JAXB. Tried changing encoding property in Marshaller to Unicode and ASCII, but it doesn’t work. After marshall, multiple lines of text are present one by one as expected. But after unmarshall, all lines come in a same line (got wrapped up). 
Using CDATAAdapter along with CharacterEscapeHandler resolves the issue but I want to know a way without usage of CharacterEscapeHandler.
Please reply if there is a way to retain the \n character after unmarshall in XML Attribute instead of having whitespace for it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation by default will not strip of any new line characters.

**Java Model (Foo)**

Below is a simple Java model with one `String` property.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private String bar;

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

The demo code below will convert the XML to objects and then write it back to XML.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum16690011/input.xml");
        Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

The input and output both contain the new line characters.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
    <bar>
        A
        B
        C
    </bar>
</foo>
```

---

**UPDATE**

If your property has an `XmlAdapter` associated with it via an `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation then this may explain the behaviour.

**CollapsedStringAdapter**

When the JAXB model is generated from an XML Schema and a node is of type `xs:token` then it will be annotated like:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
public String getBar() {
    return bar;
}
```

You would get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo>
    <bar>A B C</bar>
</foo>
```

**NormalizedStringAdapter**

When the JAXB model is generated from an XML Schema and a node is of type `xs:normalizedString` then it will be annotated like:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(NormalizedStringAdapter.class)
public String getBar() {
    return bar;
}
```

You would get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
    <bar>         A         B         C     </bar>
</foo>
```